# Mapping array values and find every matched collection

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm a newbie in Mongodb and I am currently stuck at a problem: finding all the matching documents in an array of uids.

I have this sample document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65e9c7f87686dcd9e44e55c9"
  },
  "uid": "",
  "techStack": [
    "QgyHeSce",
    "RrYcrkSv"
  ]
}
```

techStack is an array of uids of a collection 'technologies':

```
{
  "uid": "RrYcrkSv",
  "name": "Angular",
  "url": "https://www.angular.io/"
}
```

I want to map through the array of uids, and find all the matching documents in the technologies and join the results to experience document like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65e9c7f87686dcd9e44e55c9"
  },
  "uid": "",
  "techStack": [
    "QgyHeSce",
    "RrYcrkSv"
  ],
  "technologies": [
   {
     "uid": "RrYcrkSv",
     "name": "Angular",
     "url": "https://www.angular.io/"
   }
  ]
}
```

In postgresql, it is possible to do this kind of query structur by using JOIN clause. Is it possible to do this in mongodb?

I have this initial aggregation but I find it almost impossible to the query. I tried to find answers through the mongodb documentation but the aggregation in there are not the same as the structure that I am using.

```
  .aggregate([
    {
      $unwind: "$techStack"
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "technologies",
        localField: "techStack",
        foreignField: "uid",
        as: "matchedTechnologies"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$matchedTechnologies"
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        techStack: { $push: "$techStack" },
        matchedTechnologies: { $push: "$matchedTechnologies" }
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        matchedTechnologies: {
          $map: {
            input: "$techStack",
            as: "techId",
            in: {
              $first: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$technologies",
                  as: "tech",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$tech.uid", "$$techId"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unset": [
        "techStack"
      ]
    }
  ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `$lookup`. No need to `$unwind` and `$group`:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "technologies",
      localField: "techStack",
      foreignField: "uid",
      as: "technologies"
  }}
])
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VBtTvJtge_I)